# Ajax posting of FormData is hitting success but not hitting VB.Net Function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

I'm attempting to upload a file with ajax and vb.net in webforms.  I'm currently getting a success response from ajax but i'm never actually hitting a breakpoint on the backend and nothing is being uploaded or stopping code execution.  This is my first time attempting this so i'm not sure how to handle the backend specifically and everything I have found online hasn't fit my exact specifications.  The file needs to be uploaded directly into the db column as varbinary.  Almost all files will be less than 256kb so I have decided not to store them in a file system.

```
<input class="pull-left" type="file" id="fileToUpload"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="uploadDoc">Upload</button>
```

```
uploadButton.on("click", function () {
    var form = new FormData();
    var inputFile = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
    form.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);
    alert(inputFile.files.length);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../secure/shipments.aspx/UploadFile',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error uploading the file.  " + xhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
        },
        cache: false
    });
});
```

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Sub UploadFile()
        Try
            Dim file As HttpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("file")
            Dim fname As String = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
            Dim ftype As String = file.ContentType
            Dim sDatasource As String = String.Empty
            Dim inputArray(flen) As Byte
            Dim myStream As System.IO.Stream
            If (Current.Request.Files.Count > 1) Then
                file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("file")
                fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
                ftype = file.ContentType
                flen = file.ContentLength

                myStream = file.InputStream
                'read the file into the byte array
                myStream.Read(inputArray, 0, flen)
            End If
            If Not HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("datasource") Is Nothing Then sDatasource = HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("datasource").ToString()
            Using con As New SqlConnection(sDatasource)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                    cmd.CommandText = "test_insertDoc"
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("referenceno", 0)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doctype", ftype)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("line", 0)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("uploadedfile", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = inputArray
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer", 0)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("warehouse", 0)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

DB Structure:
[image: DB Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright turns out you can't or I don't know how to post files to .aspx pages so I ended up creating a .ashx handler page.

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim postedfile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files("file")
        Dim ftype As String = postedfile.ContentType
        Dim flen As Integer = postedfile.ContentLength
        Dim mystream As System.IO.Stream = postedfile.InputStream
        Dim inputArray(flen) As Byte
        Dim datasource As String = String.Empty

        mystream.Read(inputArray, 0, flen)

        If Not HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("datasource") Is Nothing Then datasource = HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents("datasource").ToString()
        Try
            Using con As New SqlConnection(datasource)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                    cmd.CommandText = "test_insertDoc"
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("referenceno", "2")
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("doctype", ftype)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("line", 0)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("uploadedFile", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = inputArray

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer", "0")
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("warehouse", "0")
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim message As String = ex.Message
        End Try
End Sub
```

```
$.ajax({
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '../secure/FileUpload.ashx',
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("There was an error uploading the file.  " + xhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
    },
    cache: false
});
```